# javascript get substring between two sets of characters

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have the following string:

```
var myString = '<p><i class="someclass"></i><img scr="somesource"/><img class="somefunnyclass" id="{{appName}}someExtraStuff.fileExt"/><span class="someclass"></span></p>';
```

how can i get with the least code the **someExtraStuff.fileExt** section?

should i do indexOf `{{appName}}` and then until the next **`"/>`** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for the pattern `{{appName}}` and take all characters who are not quotes. Then take the second element of the match.

```js
var string = '<p><i class="someclass"></i><img scr="somesource"/><img class="somefunnyclass" id="{{appName}}someExtraStuff.fileExt"/><span class="someclass"></span></p>',
    substring = (string.match(/\{\{appName\}\}([^"]+)/) || [])[1]

console.log(substring);
```

Comment: could you please explain your regex pattern? will it work if the ending is **`"/>`** or **`" />`** (with space) ?

Comment: it looks just for all characters who are not `"`. it works for both versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with three methods

// 1 option
For single `match`

```
var regex = /\{\{appName\}\}([^"]+)/;
var myString = '<p class="somefunnyclass" id="{{appName}}someExtraStuff.fileExt"/>';
console.log(myString.match(regex)[1]);
```

// 2 option
For multiple `matches`

```
var regex = /\{\{appName\}\}([^"]+)/g;
var myString = '<p class="somefunnyclass" id="{{appName}}someExtraStuff.fileExt"/>';
var temp;
var resultArray = [];
while ((temp = regex.exec(myString)) != null) {
    resultArray.push(temp[1]);
}
console.log(resultArray);
```

// 3 option For `indexOf`

```
var firstIndex= myString.indexOf("{{appName}}");
var lastIndex =firstIndex+ myString.substring(firstIndex).indexOf('"/>')
var finalString = myString.substring(firstIndex,lastIndex).replace("{{appName}}","");
console.log(finalString);
```